# JavaScript Variables adds themselves and stacks up

Tags: javascript, html, variables

So when I want to calculate `variable1 + variable2 * variable3` it only add themselves and stacks up.
Code:

```js
function randomRange(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function func() {
    var pxL = localStorage["pxL"];
    var val = document.getElementById("bp").innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("bp").innerHTML = funcCalc(val, randomRange(1, 10), pxL);
}
function funcCalc(val, random, px) {
    return val + random * px;
}
```

The thing is that in HTML document there is element which indicates the variable, and the variable would add itself + random and multiply by third variable on button click. The problem is that the variables calculate themselves and instead of changing the innerHTML, they adds it to innerHTML.
HTML:

```html
<stat id="bpT">BPT: <textarea class="statIndic" id="bp" disabled>0</textarea></stat>
```

I want output like `15` and not `015` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get an integer, not a string:

```
    var pxL = parseFloat(localStorage["pxL"]);
    var val = parseFloat(document.getElementById("bp").innerHTML);
    document.getElementById("bp").innerHTML = funcCalc(val, randomRange(1, 10), pxL);
```

`.innerHTML` returns a string for sure. Depending on how you store the variable, `localStorage` might return a string or number.

---

You can also use `Number()`:

```
    var pxL = Number(localStorage["pxL"]);
    var val = Number(document.getElementById("bp").innerHTML);
```